# How can I achieve IF ELSE under clause of WHERE?

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to use **If Else** (or similar case determining tech:) under filterring clause of **WHERE**.
Here is my sample code.

```
select * from some_table
where 
record_valid_flg = 1 and
if(user_param = '1')
then age > 20
else
name like 'Mr%'
end if
```

How can I figure it out. I would really appreciated any suggestions.. Thanks!

Comment: Now I got right and valuable answers. thanks for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use CASE like this:

```
select * from some_table
   where 
    record_valid_flg = 1 
    and CASE
      WHEN user_param = '1' THEN age > 20
      ELSE name like 'Mr%'
     END;
```

Comment: Now your answers will fix my problem. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
CASE WHEN user_param = '1' THEN age > 20 ELSE name like 'Mr%' END
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the [CASE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx);

```
SELECT * from some_table
WHERE  record_valid_flg = 1 
AND
CASE 
     WHEN  (user_param = '1') THEN age > 20 
     ELSE name like 'Mr%' 
END
```

Comment: Thanks for well format answer. But I accept by order of time. Thanks for your valuable times.

Comment: I thought I was the 1st to answer but saw the other results later!

Comment: @Nadeem_MK you may be under misconception

Comment: I want to accept your answer for accepted due to well formatted and right for me. But when I checked , compare with my accepted answer , another one is more earlier than it. If you some trouble things , that will my mistake. I'm really sorry. But anything else , Thanks for all.

Comment: No problem ;)
I included a link for the CASE for you, so you can document yourself upon it!

Comment: @ Nadeem_MK , Thanks bro.. have a nice day. I think these may be differ by secs.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it like this

```
SELECT 
    *
FROM some_table
WHERE record_valid_flg = 1
    AND IF(user_param = '1', age > 20, name LIKE 'Mr%')
```